# IDLE and python is different, not able to install modules properly

Tags: python, python-idle

thanks for reading this. I am using macOS High Sierra. I am not very familiar with terminal or environment variables, but am trying to learn more. From reading other threads and google, it seems like I either have multiple pythons installed, or have pythons running from different paths. However I am not able to find a solution to resolving this, either by re-pathing my IDLE or deleting it entirely.

I do have python, python launcher, and anaconda (not very sure how anaconda works, have it installed a few years back and didn't touch it) installed. I am trying to install pandas (`pip install pandas`), which tells me that I have it installed, but when I run it on IDLE, it says module not found. Though if i run `python3` on terminal and type my code in, it works (so pandas has indeed been installed).

When i run `which python` on terminal, it returns
`/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/python`
(when i enter into this directory from terminal, it shows that in the bin folder, I have python, python.app, python3, python3-config, python3.7, python3.7-config, python3.7m, python3.7m-config)

When i run `which idle` on terminal, it returns
`/usr/bin/idle` (im not even sure how to find this directory from the terminal)

When i run `import os; print(os.path)` on IDLE, it returns `module 'posixpath' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py'`

Would really appreciate some help to figure out how to ensure that when i install modules from terminal, it would be installed into the same python as the one IDLE is using. Also, I would like to know whether it is possible for me to work on VSCode instead of IDLE. I cant seem to find suitable extensions for data science and its related modules (like statsmodels, pandas etc). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I strongly think this is something related to the environment. But I don't use IDLE.. so not sure. Did you set up an environment to work on this project?

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço nope, I just edited on IDLE and saved the file on my desktop and ran it.

Comment: Can you check if IDLE also exists in your anaconda bundle? Its location should be `/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/idle`

Comment: @kyriakosSt i do have idle3, idle3.7 in the bundle if i look into the directory manually on terminal. though when i run which idle it directs me to the `/usr/bin/idle` one.

Comment: as a quickfix, you can manually run that `/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/idle3` from your terminal rather than typing `idle` (which "redirects" you to `/usr/bin/idle`). This IDLE version, being the anaconda one, should be using the same python as your python command and so, it will have pandas installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First of all, a quick description of anaconda:

Anaconda is meant to help you manage multiple python "environments", each one potentially having its own python version and installed packages (with their own respective versions). This is really useful in cases where you would like multiple python versions for different tasks or when there is some conflict in versions of packages, required by other ones. By default, anaconda creates a "base" environment with a specific python version, IDLE and pip. Also, anaconda provides an improved way (with respect to `pip`) of installing and managing packages via the command `conda install <package-name>`.

For the rest, I will be using the word "vanilla" to refer to the python/installation that you manually set up, independent of anaconda.

#### Explanation of the problem:

Now, the problem arises since you also installed python independently. The details of the problem depend on how exactly you set up both python and anaconda, so I cannot tell you exactly what went wrong. Also, I am not an OSX user, so I have no idea how python is installed and what it downloads/sets alongside.
By your description however, it seems that the "vanilla" python installation did not overwrite neither your anaconda python nor anaconda's pip, but it did install IDLE and set it up to use this new python.

So right now, when you are downloading something via `pip`, only the python from anaconda is able to see that and not IDLE's python.

### Possible solutions:

#### 1. Quick fix:

Just run IDLE via `/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/idle3` every time. This one uses anaconda's python and **should** be able to see all packages installed via `conda install` of `pip install` **(*)**. I get this is tiresome, but you don't have to delete anything. You can also set an "alias" in your `~/.bashrc` file to make the command `idle` specifically linking you there. Let me know with a comment if you would like me to explain how to do that, as this answer will get too long and redundant.

#### 2. Remove conda altogether (not recommended)

You can search google on how to uninstall anaconda along with everything that it has installed. What I do not know at this point is whether your "vanilla" python will become the default, whether you will need to also manually install pip again and whether there is the need to reinstall python in order for everything to work properly.

#### 3. Remove your python "vanilla" installation and only use anaconda

Again, I do not know how python installation works in OSX, but it should be reasonably straightforward to uninstall it. The problem now is that probably you will not have a launcher for IDLE (since I am guessing anaconda doesn't provide one on OSX) but you will be able to use it via the terminal as described in **1.**.

#### 4. Last resort:

If everything fails, simply uninstall both your vanilla python (which I presume will also uninstall IDLE) and anaconda which will uninstall its own python, pip and idle versions. The relevant documentation should not be difficult to follow. Then, reinstall whichever you want anew.

### Finally:

When you solve your problems, any IDE you choose, being VScode (I haven't use that either), pycharm or something else, will probably be able to integrate with your installed python. There is no need to install a new python "bundle" with every IDE.

---

**(*)**: Since you said that after typing `pip install pandas` your anaconda's python can import pandas while IDLE cannot, I am implying in my answer that pip is also the one that comes with anaconda. You can make sure this is the case by typing `which pip` which should point to an anaconda directory, probably `/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin/pip`

Comment: Cheers! Just so that other people will be helped as well, can you mention which option did you choose?

Comment: i chose the first option, it was the quickest, and didn't have a risk of me accidentally deleting/not deleting/creating things wrongly!

Answer (score 1):

First: This would be a comment if I had enough reputation.

Second: I would just delete python. Everything. And reinstall it.

Comment: Do I delete anaconda with it? And does it work if I just delete python launcher, IDLE, and empty trash? Or are there additional steps with deleting and uninstalling IDLE as a mac user? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah delete anaconda also, google will probably tell you how to do that. Then just drag all the Python stuff from Application to trash, and downlod latest Python from www.python.org.

Comment: I don't know what to delete because I never had this problem. But to be sure I would delete everything.

Comment: @ruohola Do i have to download anaconda afterwards? Or python through anaconda? I am enrolled in an online data science course, and it says the pre-req for the lesson is to download both python and anaconda :) thanks!

Comment: Well then you need both of them obviously :) After deleting everything I would search for some macOS anaconda specific installation tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat and summarized what has been said on various other question answers:

1a. 3rd party packages are installed for a particular python(3).exe binary.

1b. To install multiple packages to multiple binaries, see the option from `python -m pip -h`.

2. To find out which python binary is running, execute `import sys; print(sys.executable)`.

3a. For 3rd party package xyz usually installed in some_python/Lib/site-packages, IDLE itself has nothing to do with whether `import xyz` works.  It only matters whether xyz is installed for 'somepython' (see 1a).

3b. To run IDLE with 'somepython', run `somepython -m idlelib` in a terminal or console.
`somepython` can be a name recognized by the OS or a path to a python executable.